# Missing right parenthesis while import data from flat files to table

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have `load data infile ....` one flat file. I want to load the data into table **tab** from this flat file. I want to pass few values like '**ab**', '**cd**', '**ef**' in column **col6** of the table. When i write the code in the flat file like this

```
load data infile <source-path>
into tab
fields terminated by ','
(
 col1 "TRIM(:col1)" ,
 ............
 ...........
 col6 "('ab','cd','ef')",
 ..........)
```

But when i load this file into the table then i found an error `ORA-00907: Missing Right Parenthesis`. How to resolve this error so that i can insert value of '**ab**', '**cd**', '**ef**' in **col6** of table **tab**.

Comment: The trim function doesn't take three arguments... what are you actually trying to do? Create three rows from one line in your loaded file?

Comment: @AlexPoole I want to insert these above '**ab**', '**cd**', '**ef**' data into **col6** the table **tab**.

Comment: Three values in one column? How does that work? Is it a nested table perhaps? Please edit your question to show the table DDL, a sample data file, the whole control file and the expected results.

Comment: @AlexPoole Not 3 values in one column. These are 3 different values which is store into different records. Means '**ab**' in any other records, '**cd**' in another records & '**ef**' in another record. Each value will store only for one distinct column.

Comment: So for each row you load from the flat file, you want to add 3 rows to the table, one for each of those col6 values? Please edit your question to show your expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [a multitable insert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-control-file-contents.html#GUID-7C0925AD-7156-4C30-BF19-3C3D3628A7DE), with three inserts into the same table:

```
load data infile <source-path>
into tab
fields terminated by ','
(
 col1 "TRIM(:col1)" ,
 ............
 ...........
 col6 CONSTANT 'ab',
 ..........)
into tab
fields terminated by ','
(
 col1 POSITION(1) "TRIM(:col1)" ,
 ............
 ...........
 col6 CONSTANT 'cd',
 ..........)
into tab
fields terminated by ','
(
 col1 POSITION(1) "TRIM(:col1)" ,
 ............
 ...........
 col6 CONSTANT 'ef',
 ..........)
```

The `POSITION(1)` resets to the start of the record, so it sees the same values from the source record again fir each insert. [Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-field-list-contents.html#GUID-5363ACC6-C3A4-4174-8517-1689A702A7C7).

---

Alternatively you could insert into a staging table, with a single row for each record in your file, and excluding the constant-value `col6` completely - which you could with SQL*Loader:

```
load data infile <source-path>
into staging_tab
fields terminated by ','
(
 col1 "TRIM(:col1)" ,
 ............
 ...........
 col5 ...
 col7 ...
 ..........)
```

... or [as an external table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-external-tables-concepts.html); and then insert into your real table by querying the staging table and cross-joining with a CTE containing the constant values:

```
insert into tab (col1, col2, ..., col6, ...)
with constants (col6) as (
            select 'ab' from dual
  union all select 'cd' from dual
  union all select 'ef' from dual
)
select st.col1, st.col2, ..., c.col6, ...
from staging_tab st
cross join constants c;
```

For each row in the staging table you'll get three rows in the real table, one for each of the dummy rows in the CTE. You could do the same with with a collection instead of a CTE:

```
insert into tab (col1, col2, col6)
select st.col1, st.col2, c.column_value
from staging_tab st
cross join table(sys.odcivarchar2list('ab', 'cd', 'ef')) c;
```

This time you get one row for each element in the collection - which is expanded into multiple rows by the table collection clause. The result is the same.

Comment: But in my table we are using 67 columns. So if i use like this then the flat becomes more complicated & it'll take more time to compile. Is there any way to insert data without inserting the whole column for each time.

Comment: @user8487380 - seems like a one-off setup cost. Alternatively you could insert one row per record into a staging table without that column, and insert 3 rows into your real table from that staging table. Or run the load three times with the same (maybe null) column value and then update those with the real values. Staging table is possibly simplest. (And that can be an external table if the data file is on the DB server).

Comment: It means we have to insert 3 times that you mentioned above. But if the constant value is too much high and column of the table is also too much then we have to apply same method for insert.

Comment: @user8487380 - I've added a brief example of how to do it with a staging table instead.

Comment: these DML query i have to write in same flat file or in different files.

Comment: The DML insert would be a separate step after running SQL\*Loader, run through SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer or whatever client you use.